# Mac G5 - Nvidia GeForce 5200 FX settings

Tags: nvidia, powerpc, settings

I finally was able to install Debian on my powerpc, but the only way to get a GUI up is by disabling nouveau. I just use Linux `nouveau.modeset=0` at the yaboot prompt. However my color is all messed up like it's been washed in tie-dye.

I'm guessing I need to configure an xorg.conf to get the card to work? I have no idea what settings to put in there. Using an Nvidia GeForce 5200 FX with 64mb vram on a MAC G5.

Answer (score 1):

Adding boot parameters to force different display modes may help. I've been able to get Fedora Core 17 up on my powermac g5 by forcing the display to use the DVI-I-2 interface and disabling the rest.

http://www.mintppc.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=5497#p5497

Answer (score 0):

If `nouveau` is not working, you cannot do [anything](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1769801) more than switch back to [good old](http://mac.linux.be/content/xorgconf-g5-ppc-tower) `nv`. PPC & Intel have different architecture with different [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). It's quite hard to manage this **and** reverse-engineer how the hardware is working : I guess you should not expect a fix for this in new versions of *nouveau*.

There's also a quite good proprietary driver made by NVIDIA.

Comment: The nVidia proprietary driver isn't available for PowerPC machines (as is the case), sadly. The only options one has in this case are `nouveau` and `nv`.